# Django multiple models that have a foreign key to another model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Example:

A system that processes different types of csv files. The different types of csv files have different content inside.

So the current way im thinking about modeling this is:

File model that stores some generic info about each file processed, like the name, date etc.

```
class File(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField()
```

Then models that stores the content for each type of file and these models link back to the File model:

```
class Example1File(models.Model):
    file = models.ForeignKey(File, related_name=example_file_1_content)
    ... (all columns for this file)
```

```
class Example2File(models.Model):
    file = models.ForeignKey(File, related_name=example_file_2_content)
    ... (all columns for this file)
```

Is there an easy way for example to loop through the files table and get the content for each file and django would just know in which table to go look?

```
for file in File.objects.all():
   file.???
```

Or would I only be able to do this by storing a type field on the file and then getting the content with the reverse relationship like this.

```
for file in File.objects.all():
   if file.type == FileTypes.ExampleFile1:
      file.example_file_1_content
```

But what if there are a lot of different file types? Im still in the process of learning about how django handles relationships/reverse relationships so I might just not be there yet or the way I am modeling this is not optimal.

Thanks in advance.